# JavaScript, HTML, JSON: No puedo cargar un archivo JSON

Tags: javascript, html, json

Soy un completo novato en JavaScript y HTML; Hoy empece a aprender y quiero hacer una especie de "Google Drive" (privado, solo para mis amigos/familiares) pero para guardar solo texto y/o links de pags. web. Entonces cada perfil tendria un JSON donde estarian sus textos guardados

No sabia como usar JavaScript con archivos JSON, asi que busque en youtube y copie un codigo de youtube:

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    
          var archivo = new XMLHttpRequest();
          archivo.open('GET', "data.json");
    
          archivo.onload = function() {
    
              if (archivo.status == 200) {
        
                  var data = JSON.parse(archivo.responseText);
        
                  if (data.Text == "prueba") // Hice una preuba, ese texto no esta en el JSON {
                      var datos = document.getElementById("texto");
                      datos.innerHTML = `
                        <h1>Falso</h1>
                  `;
                  }
        
               }
    
          };
    
        archivo.send();
    
    };
</script>
```

Me maree un poco, y creo que lo escribi mal o no esta funcionando

JSON:

```
{
    "Text" : "TextoDEPruebaTextoDEPruebaTextoDEPrueba"
}
```

Perdon si lo escribi o explique mal, soy nuevo y no se muy bien como explicarlo...

¿Esta mal escrito o no esta funcionando por algun motivo?

Comment: Si el texto se prueva en el archivo es: `TextoDEPruebaTextoDEPruebaTextoDEPrueba`, ¿Porque lo comparas con `prueba`? antes de ese `if` coloca un `console.log(data.Text);` para ver que datos tienes guardado, tambien conaeguí un error de sintaxis, pones `{` dentro de un comentario: `if (data.Text=="prueba")// Hice una preuba, ... {`

Comment: `..............`

Comment: `}` y lo que sucede es un error de sintaxis porque el interpre de JavaScript no puede encontrar la el incio y encuentra el final. y como resultado te lanzaria un error. intenta tambien ponerlo: `if(data.Text=="TextoDEPruebaTextoDEPruebaTextoDEPrueba"){// Hice una preuba, ...`

Comment: @DanielBriceño ¿Puedes ponerme el codigo con esas observaciones agregadas en una respuesta? Gracias.

Comment: si estás empezando, te recomiendo que uses [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/fetch) en lugar de un objeto XmlHttpRequest. Es más sencillo y es un API más actual

Comment: @Skeletoos57 No estoy muy seguro de que ese comentario sea la solucion que buscabas, por eso lo dejo en un comentario.

Comment: ¿Tiene que ver que el JSON y todo el codigo esta en un usb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suponiendo que tu archivo se llame data.json y este ubicado en el mismo directorio que el script:

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    
          var archivo = new XMLHttpRequest();
          archivo.open('GET', "data.json");
    
          archivo.onload = function() {
    
              if (archivo.status == 200) {
        
                  var data = JSON.parse(archivo.responseText);
        
                  if (data.Text == "TextoDEPruebaTextoDEPruebaTextoDEPrueba") // Hice una preuba, ese texto no esta en el JSON {
                      var datos = document.getElementById("texto");
                      datos.innerHTML = `
                        <h1>${data.text}</h1>
                  `;
                  }else  datos.innerHTML = `
                        <h1>falso</h1>
        
               }
    
          };
    
        archivo.send();
    
    };
</script>
```

Comment: access to XMLHttpRequest at 'DIRECTORIO' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https.
doc.html:39 | GET "DIRECTORIO" net::ERR_FAILED -- Me aparece el mismo error

Comment: Los httprequest no permiten leer archivos del disco. Eso se me paso. Puedes usar la api fetch para hacer la peticion (desde firefox, chrome tambien da problemas). Esto del cors esvun fastidio necesario al cual deberas acostumbrarte

Comment: Y como evitar el cors esvun , porque yo tengo el mismo problema, cómo leer archivo json en local ??